# PySpark pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc() doesn't accept datetime type upperbound argument as document says

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-jdbc

I found in the document for jdbc function in `PySpark 3.0.1` at
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader, it says:

> column – the name of a column of numeric, date, or timestamp type that
> will be used for partitioning.

I thought it accepts a datetime column to partition the query.

So I tried this on `EMR-6.2.0` (PySpark 3.0.1):

```
sql_conn_params = get_spark_conn_params()  # my function
sql_conn_params['column'] ='EVENT_CAPTURED'
sql_conn_params['numPartitions'] = 8
# sql_conn_params['upperBound'] = datetime.strptime('2016-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d') # another trial
# sql_conn_params['lowerBound'] = datetime.strptime(''2016-01-10', '%Y-%m-%d')
sql_conn_params['upperBound'] = '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
sql_conn_params['lowerBound'] = '2016-01-10 00:00:00'
df = (spark.read.jdbc(
    table=tablize(sql),
    **sql_conn_params
))
df.show()
```

I got this error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 625, in jdbc
    return self._df(self._jreader.jdbc(url, table, column, int(lowerBound), int(upperBound),
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
```

I looked at the source code here
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py#L865
and found it doesn't support datetime type as document says.

My question is:

It doesn't support datetime type partition column in PySpark as the code shows, but why the document says it supports it?

Thanks,

Yan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It supports.**

The issue here is that the `spark.read.jdbc` method currently only supports parameters upper/lower bounds for integral type columns.

But you can use `load` method and `DataFrameReader.option` to specifiy `upperBound` and `lowerBound` for other column types date/timestamp :

```
df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://server/db") \
    .option("dbtable", "table_name") \
    .option("user", "user") \
    .option("password", "xxxx") \
    .option("partitionColumn", "EVENT_CAPTURED") \
    .option("lowerBound", "2016-01-01 00:00:00") \
    .option("upperBound", "2016-01-10 00:00:00") \
    .option("numPartitions", "8") \
    .load()
```

Or by passing dict of options:

```
df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .options(*sql_conn_params)\
    .load()
```

You can see all available options and examples here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

Comment: Thank you @blackbishop. So it doesn't support datetime bound in PySpark as the document says, right ?

Comment: Hi @syan, That's it. There is some confusion in the docs.